# htaccess to Web.Config conversion

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, yii2

I want to convert below portion of .htaccess to Web.Config.I tried many times but its not working properly.please could anyone help me.

```
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2007/(admin)
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2017/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|files|uploads)/
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working yet?

Comment: I convert this to web.config using online convertion tool but its not redircting proper folders.First time i am hoting iis.@NicoHaase

Comment: Can you not use IISs import htaccess feature..? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Comment: So please share the parts of your code that are not working yet, such that we can help

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2007/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|files|uploads)/ this portion how to convert @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess is a bit complicated, I think that there is an easier and efficient way.
Anyway,  web config is a torture; and  IISs import htaccess feature is a bad joke. 
This solution works for me:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
            <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule backend js deal" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^admin/js/(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/backend/web/js/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <!-- the other assets here -->

            <!-- this must be BEFORE frontend rule -->
            <rule name="rule admin url deal" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^admin(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/backend/web/index.php" />
            </rule>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Check this solution from backend, and apply to frontend. If you have some problem with some url, please, write me.

Comment: i debug the issue i am updte the question.This portion how to convert web config

Comment: You must use individual rules as described above. But, I have a question: All routes in your domain is under /2017/?  in that case, you can configure IIS to use yourdomain.com/2017/ as baseurl